# How to fix:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/monkeybu/public_html/index.php on line 2

Tags: php, html, css

Can some one help me fix this?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/monkeybu/public_html/index.php on line 2
I am using x10hosting for my host.
Here's my code:

```
  <?php
    require_once "lib/steam-condenser.php",
    require_once "config.php";
    $id = $_GET['sid'];
    $getData = SteamId::create($id);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.maximage.css" type="text/css"      media="screen" title="CSS" charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/progressbar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section id="downloadInfo">
        <div id="progressBarText"><span id="fileName">filename.vmt </span><span id="downloadPresent"><b>0%</b></span></div>
        <div id="progressBar"><div></div> </div>
    </section>
    <section id="playerInfo" style="margin-left: 15%;">
    <?php
    echo '
        <img src="'.$getData->getFullAvatarUrl().'" width="299">
        <ul>
            <li style="width: 70%;"><h1 id="serverName">serverName</h1></li>
            <li style="width: 60%;"><h2>'.$getData->getNickname().'<span class="steamid">['.SteamId::convertCommunityIdToSteamId($id).']</span></h2></li>
            <li style="width: 50%;"><h3 id="mapName">mapName</h3></li>
        </ul>';
    ?>
    </section>
    <?php
        if($loadingScreen['backgroundMusic'] != "")
        {
            $ytLink = explode("v=", $loadingScreen['backgroundMusic']);
            echo '<iframe width="1" height="1" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$ytLink[1].'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" style="opacity: 0;"></iframe>';
        }
    ?>
    <div id="maximage">
        <?php
        $imgDir = scandir("images/backgrounds/");
        $picNum = 0;
        foreach($imgDir as &$files)
        {
            $picNum++;
            if($picNum >= 3)
            {
                echo "<img src='images/backgrounds/".$files."' alt='' width='1400' height='1050' />\n";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js'></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maximage.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function(){
            jQuery('#maximage').maximage();
        });

        function GameDetails( servername, serverurl, mapname, maxplayers, steamid, gamemode ) 
        {
            document.getElementById("serverName").innerHTML = servername;
            document.getElementById("mapName").innerHTML = mapname;
        }
        function SetFilesTotal( total ) { 
            var totalFiles = total;
        }
        function SetFilesNeeded( needed ) { 
            var filesLeft = needed;
            var present = (totalFiles / filesLeft);
            document.getElementById("downloadPresent").innerHTML = present +     "%";
            progressBar(Math.round(present), $('#progressBar'));
        }
        function DownloadingFile( fileName ) {
            document.getElementById("fileName").innerHTML = fileName;
        }
    </script>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

config:

```
<?php
$loadingScreen['backgroundMusic'] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UjsXo9l6I8";     //Only youtube links.. (for now). (if you dont want to play music leave it blank) 
?>
```

steam:

```
<?php
/**
 * This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the new BSD License.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Sebastian Staudt
 *
 * @author  Sebastian Staudt
 * @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php New BSD License
 * @package steam-condenser
 */

define('STEAM_CONDENSER_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
define('STEAM_CONDENSER_VERSION', '1.3.6');

require_once STEAM_CONDENSER_PATH . 'steam/community/SteamId.php';
```

Comment: comma should be semi-colon, you should of been able to fix that in less time than it took to post

Comment: Read the error message ... file: index.php, line: 2, error: unexpected "," !

Comment: +1 Credit goes to you @Dagon --- I'll see you in Costa Rica, lunch is on me, and the vodka too ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
require_once "lib/steam-condenser.php",
                                //-   ^ should be a semi-colon
```

should have a semi-colon and not a comma

```
require_once "lib/steam-condenser.php";
```

Dagon, sorry I saw your comment after I posted this.

Comment: you just want easy rep points

Comment: @Dagon Nah, it was too easy. I just want this thing closed and put a fancy graphical outline `//-   ^` ;-) Gotta put my graphics knowledge to good use!

Comment: However, I did go over the rest of the OP's code just to make sure. @Dagon

Comment: changed it but still the same problem... :/

Comment: What do you mean by "the same problem"? `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/monkeybu/public_html/index.php on line 2` ? @user3385073

Comment: i changed it to a ';' and got this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/monkeybu/public_html/config.php on line 2 - sorry didnt mean the same error

Comment: I'm suspecting the error may be inside the `steam-condenser.php` file. @user3385073

Comment: And/or your `config.php` file. Can you update your question with the codes that are in both those files? `config.php` and `steam-condenser.php` @user3385073

Comment: I edited your question because of many missing indents, however I'm unsure if what you added was for the two included/require files. @user3385073

Comment: I added the config.php and steam-condenser.php from the folder...

Comment: I went over your revised code and for the life of me I can't find the problem. I did test it to a certain extent and found no parse error, yet I am questioning this line `$loadingScreen['backgroundMusic'] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UjsXo9l6I8";` which I tend to think should be `$loadingScreen = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UjsXo9l6I8";` @user3385073 besides that, I can't tell for sure. There has been a request to reopen the question and I will vote for it also, hoping someone else can be of further help if I can't find it before.

Comment: To add to my above comment, this `if($loadingScreen['backgroundMusic'] != "")` would probably need to be changed to `if($loadingScreen != "")` @user3385073 but I could be wrong.

Comment: thanks anyways :) I'll try it again and the background music thing worked anyway but maybe if i change that it will fix the problem? but doubt it :/

Comment: You're welcome. It's really hard to tell, you can try it but I too, tend to think it may not work. @user3385073 I voted to reopen, so will see who else will vote also. Hoping for a solution.

Comment: There's another line which I am questioning `echo '<iframe width="1" height="1" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'` shouldn't there be a `http:` in there? I.e.: `echo '<iframe width="1" height="1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'` @user3385073